# Angular: why isn't $evalAsync called $applyAsync?

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, definition, angularjs-digest

Angular beginner question about scopes ([docs here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope)).

1. `$eval` executes an expression in the context of a scope.
2. `$apply` basically calls `$eval` and then `$digest`.
3. Why does `$evalAsync` call `$digest` too (or, more precisely, ensure `$digest` is called)?

It seems to be that `$`*`eval`*`Async` should really be called `$`*`apply`*`Async`, doesn't it?

I'm a beginner -- what am I missing?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://teropa.info/blog/2013/11/03/make-your-own-angular-part-1-scopes-and-digest.html) for some nice explanation of $evalAsync/$eval/$digest/$apply

Comment: @dimirc That's actually the article where I'm coming from and still didn't get it. Sorry I'm a noob!

Answer (score 3):

`$evalAsync` and `$applyAsync` target to different situations.

**$evalAsync**: defers the expression to the **next loop iteration of current digest cycle**. One Angular digest cycle loops for a few times until no data is dirty. If no digest cycle is in progress, it will start a new digest cycle (call `$apply` method) and evaluate the expression (call `$eval` method)  in it. This method is useful if you call a function out of Angular scope but still like to digest the dirty data when a digest cycle is already in progress, in which case you cannot call `$apply`.

**$applyAsync**: defers the expression to **the next cycle of digest**. It always starts a new cycle of digest to after the expression is evaluated (call `$apply` method). This method is useful if you frequently execute some service call back (like `$http` service) out Angular scope with dirty scope data. However, if it starts a digest for each callback, there may be bad performance. Therefore, this method optimize the process by share the digest cycles among several async callbacks, which outperforms the method `$evalAsync`.

Answer (score 2):

$applyAsync already exists:

> Schedule the invocation of $apply to occur at a later time. The actual time difference varies across browsers, but is typically around ~10 milliseconds.
>
> This can be used to queue up multiple expressions which need to be evaluated in the same digest

evalAsync handles digests differently:

> $evalAsync triggers a digest, and is unsuitable when it is expected that a
>   digest should not occur.
>
> Note: if this function is called outside of a $digest cycle, a new $digest cycle will be scheduled.

This behavior of this when called implicitly changed in AngularJS 1.3:

> -Previously, even if invokeApply was set to false, a $rootScope digest would occur during promise resolution. 
>   This is no longer the case, as promises returned from $timeout and $interval will no longer trigger $evalAsync
>   (which in turn causes a $digest) if invokeApply is false.
>
> Workarounds include manually triggering $scope.$apply(), or returning $q.defer().promise from a promise callback, and resolving or rejecting it when appropriate.

**References**

- [AngularJS API: $applyAsync](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$applyAsync)
- [applyAsync vs evalAsync](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2751-scope-applyasync-vs-scope-evalasync-in-angularjs-1-3.htm)

Comment: according to ben nadals eximination (http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2751-scope-applyasync-vs-scope-evalasync-in-angularjs-1-3.htm) both do the same thing, just the timing is different

Comment: @AirBorne04 No. Ben mentions  `that asynchronous expressions added by $evalAsync() from within a $watch() binding will execute in the same digest. Asynchronous expressions added by $applyAsync() from within a $watch() binding will execute at a later point in time (~10ms).`

Comment: @ Yes you are right the $evalAsync() will execute in the current digest $applyAsync() in a different one i was mainly objecting to your corrected statement of ".., while $evalAsync interprets expressions" which might have been misleading. Since you took it out i take back my vote down :)